# What is the difference between EOF and new line feed?

Tags: c

how will my code behave if I do

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
```

OR

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
```

I am currently using C language?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: One will read characters until the end of a line, the other will read until the end of the file, just as the code implies.

Comment: There's a newline at the end of every line. There's an EOF only after the last line.

Comment: @Barmar: There is no guarantee there is a new-line character at the end of every line. If the user presses control-D twice with the default terminal settings on Unix settings, the currently typed characters are sent with no new-line character, and then an EOF is indicated. If input comes from a file on disk with no terminal new-line character, there is none when read. If input comes from a pipe and the other side terminates without flushing its buffers, characters may have been sent in the pipe with no new-line character. Code should not be written to assume new-lines are present.

Comment: ch needs to be declared int, not char.

Answer (score 0):

`EOF` means `End of File`.

`\n` means "newline".

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Are you really asking me to elaborate on the difference between the difference between the terms "end of file" and "newline"?

Comment: I was hoping you could explain further to better help the asker. They don't understand the difference is and I think a longer answer would help them. I'm sorry to upset you. I didn't mean to.